# How can I populate a datagridview from top to bottom, left to right?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, datagridview

I have a table in sql server in which i stored images. Now i want to retrive all these images to datagridview. But the problem is that all the images are displayed in a single column of datagridview. I want to equally distribute the images in datagridview.Currently i am using this code

```
OdbcConnection con= dbc.openconn();
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("select itempicture from tblItems", con);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();          
da.Fill(dataTable); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
con.Close();
```

or
I would like to to have some pre-defined columns and rows for this images displayed datagridview.
I want to display these images for the front of point of sale application. Any other suggestion will be highly appreciated.
or
hwo to retrive each image to datagridview row[0]xcolumn[0] then row[0]xcolumn[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVNJD.png) then row[0]xcolumn[2]....and then row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVNJD.png)xcolumn[0]....and so on... t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                //cell.
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. how can i display image in each cell. i have a table with two row id, and pic. i will display the picture row only, that is distributed equally in the datagridview. e.g. if i have 13 pictures then i need 4 rows and 3 columns to fill in the datagridview. thank u again.